# NHibernate.IFutureValue<> when serialized includes .Value

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, serialization, jsonserializer

I'm building an ASP.NET (2.0, no, I can't change it) site with NHibernate, and have a custom JSON converter so I can not-serialize properties I want hidden from the client.  This lets me just return the objects, and never have to worry about their serialized values - they're always secure.

Unfortunately, it appears that if I use `query.FutureValue<class>()`, the object that gets serialized is first the `NHibernate.Impl.FutureValue<class>` and not my entity, which means I get JSON that looks like this if I throw it in a dictionary and return it to the client:

```
{key: { Value: { /* my serialized object properties */ } }
```

Previously I discovered that I can't get any interfaces to work in ASP's JavaScriptConverter implementations... only regular or abstract classes.  So returning `typeof(IFutureValue<MyBaseClass>)` as a supported type means my converter is completely ignored.  I can catch MyBaseClass, because I refactored things earlier to use an abstract base instead of an interface, but not the interface.

And then I discover that the FutureValue implementation in .Impl is internal to the assembly, or some other such nonsense that only serves to make my .NET experience even more painful.  So I can't use `typeof(FutureValue<MyBaseClass>)` to handle it all, because FutureValue exists only in my debugging sessions.

Is there a way to get the class type out of the assembly?  Or a way to convince ASP that interfaces do in fact have uses?  Or might there be some superclass I *can* access that would let me get around the whole issue?

Help!  I like my Futures, it lets me batch a whole heck-ton of calls at once!

(if something isn't clear, or you want more code, by all means, ask!  I can post quite a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it seems you are mixing things a together a little bit.

It sounds like you're trying to serialize an instance of `query.FutureValue<class>()`, which unsurprisingly gives you just that: a JSON object where the `Value` fields has JSON representing your entity.

To me it sounds like you *really* want to just serialize `query.FutureValue<class>().Value`.

Using NHibernate futures like this gives you little benefit though, so you're probably after something like:

```
var future1 = query1.FutureValue<SomeEntity>();
var future2 = query2.FutureValue<AnotherEntity>();

var json1 = serializer.Serialize(future1.Value); //<BAM! Multi-query gets fired!
var json2 = serializer.Serialize(future2.Value);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually, it's that ASP is serializing FutureValue<class>es for me, passing the .Value to my serializing code, and I wish to capture it further up-stream.  But FutureValue is an internal class in NHibernate, so I can't cast to it, and I can't register interfaces with the serializer (for reasons I don't yet understand).  So I'm hoping someone can tell me how to access that internal class type, so I can capture those types, instead of it always being one layer too late.

Comment: Ok - but where do you put the `FutureValue<SomeEntity>()` for ASP to serialize it? Try putting `FutureValue<SomeEntity>().Value` instead.

Comment: The JSON converter class defines a "supported types" enum.  So I have to return things like `typeof(FutureValue<SomeClass>)`.  I'm returning the objects from WebMethods, and capturing them with the JSON converter on the way out.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx